# How do I make 2-3.. parts of the file via SSH?

Tags: ssh, split, tar

How do I make two/three/.. parts of the file via SSH?

Tar file inside the server has 29 GB size.. Can I split it into parts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the split command.
For example making 1G slices from inputfile with names prefix-aa, prefix-bb,...

split -b1G inputfile prefix-